# Error with taskset

Tags: linux

I'm trying to assign a process to one core of my machine using taskset. But it gives me this error:

```
$ sudo taskset 0x00000001 -p 20145
Password: 
execvp: No such file or directory
failed to execute -p
```

What do I have to do to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Check the man page for taskset. The syntax is:

```
taskset [options] -p [mask] pid
```

so, try:

```
sudo taskset -p 0x00000001 20145
```